# Laravel Eloquent фильтр. Выборка из нескольких связанных таблиц многие - ко - многим

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть 3 таблицы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробую делать фильтр по 4 параметрам 
  2 параметра это *angle_of_rotation_a* и *angle_of_rotation_b* в таблице **turbachargers**

по *name* в таблице **motors** и **vehicles**

Вот как я делаю

```
 dd(Turbocharger::with(['motors' => function($turbine){
        $turbine->where('id', 1);
    }])->get());
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `motors`.*, `motor_turbocharger`.`turbocharger_id` as `pivot_turbocharger_id`, `motor_turbocharger`.`motor_id` as `pivot_motor_id` from `motors` inner join `motor_turbocharger` on `motors`.`id` = `motor_turbocharger`.`motor_id` where `motor_turbocharger`.`turbocharger_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141) and `id` = 1)
```

Как правильно делать выборку при many-to-many

Comment: я насчитал 5 таблиц

Comment: @n.osennij да простите таблиц 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда ты используешь метод `with(['motors'=>function($query){}])`, то в замыкании в объекте `query` ты формируешь запрос только к связанным моделям с моделью `Turbocharger`. Подробнее:

```
// with() подгружает связанные модели и не влияет на текущий результат
Turbocharger::with(['motors' => function($query){
    // получить связанные с Turbocharger
    // модели Motor, где Motor id = 1
    $query->where('id', 1);
}])
->get(); // получить все модели Turbocharger
```

Итак, по порядку.
1) чтобы ограничить количество `Turbocharger` по связанной модели `Motor`, нужно "приджойнить" подзапрос

```
// подзапрос для фильтрации
$subQuery = Motor::join('motor_turbochanger as mt','mt.motor_id','motors.id')
  ->where('motors.id', 1) // и есть ограничение
  ->select('mt.turbocharger_id') // в результате подзапроса нам нужны только идентификаторы турбочарджеров
  ->groupBy('mt.turbocharger_id'); // ну и обязательно сгруппируем

$res = Turbocharger::joinSub($subQuery, 'sub', 'sub.turbocharger_id', 'turbochargers.id')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!